# Javascript function only running on the first call

Tags: javascript

I have a function opening a new window, attached to a button:

```
<button onclick="newWin()">New Window</button>
```

This works fine but just the first time it is clicked. Following times, even when the opened window has been closed, I have this error:

> TypeError: newWin is not a function

This is the JS function:

```
function newWin() {
       newWindow= window.open('pan/newWin.html', 'Nueva ventana', 'toolbar=yes,location=no,resizable=no,width=600,height=820');}
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. What you've posted should work. There is obviously more to this problem than in your example.

Comment: are you sure that inside `newWindow=...` and not `newWin=...`? can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: That was it. Certainly it is newWin, same name as function. Thank you

Comment: Please post this as answer to tick you.

Comment: Please don’t correct your code in the question, as it invalidates the answers that solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistake:

1. try save opened window in variable with same name as function
2. not use *var* keyword.

In your case you just redefine global property *newWin* from function to object.

for solving you can rename it, or just use *var* keyword: `var newWin = window.open(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Your are assigning some object to function variable.

First time on page load `newWin()` will be loaded as function. After execution of function you are assigning some value to it .

Hence it is resulting in to error.